# PHP MYSQL and Trigger

Tags: php, triggers, md5

I'm looking for the solution to a problem. I have a form that sends two fields (ID, info_data) and I'm trying to add a third field (secuencia) by a trigger but I can not do it.

table, result and expected results
[image]

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER regi_tg
BEFORE INSERT ON registros
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.secuencia = new.id; 
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

PD: I work info_data copy data in secuencia, but not copy the ID achievement in secuencia

Answer (score 0):

Test CODE:

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE TRIGGER regi_tg AFTER INSERT ON registros FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
            SET OLD.secuencia = NEW.id;
  END;

CREATE TRIGGER regi_tg AFTER UPDATE ON registros FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
            SET OLD.secuencia = NEW.id;
  END;


END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I cant use it that trigger :( ,  #1362 - Updating of old row is not allowed in trigger

Answer (score 0):

I use this trigger and it worked, I did recently thought for a while and seeing many post but i dont know if a correct form.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCIOM.jpg)

**Trigger**

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER regi_tg
BEFORE INSERT ON registros
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET new.secuencia =   md5((SELECT ID FROM registros ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)+1); 
END$$
DELIMITER ;